# Explanation on creating a connection string for a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I'm working on connecting my SQL database to Shiprush that has SQL integration. I've went through all of the steps and read through the information on creating a SQL string, but mine didn't work.

At first I tried a SQL string like this

```
Provide=SQLOLEDB; Server=Localhost; Database=DBNAME; User Id=ID; Password=psw;
```

However  I realized that it wasn't local. So, I tried to use my IP address and port number like this but it also failed.

```
Provide=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=myIPv4:1433; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; User Id=ID; Password=psw;
```

The database is listening on port 1433. I have to use the provider SQLOLEDB. Shiprush says when I try to access the database:

> The connection string property has not been initialized

How can I get the connection string working?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Are you writing code? Or are you just trying to handle a connection string over to ShipRush and then they'll connect to your DB?

Comment: `myIPv4:1433` Usually the `port` is separate by comma not colon

Comment: I have read through connectionstrings.com info I specifically looked at strings for my SSMS https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: How it works is that I setup a connection string on their site and it allows their website to get a query into their system from my database. And allows them to send updated data back to my database.

Comment: @Squirrel you are right. I went in and fixed that, but it still says it still didn't initialize.

Comment: How about `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL` and not `Provide=MSOLEDBSQL`?

Comment: Provider=MSOLEDBSQL didn't change anything
How do I put the grey box around code in comments?

Comment: @ChaseHatten try clicking the help link next to the comment box